# How can I exclude a directory when using find

Tags: unix, find

I'm trying to use the find command in Unix and I know how to use the basics of it. For example, I have four folders, A, B, C, and D. Under each folder I have a file called `hi.dat`. To look in all folders, I would do:

`find * -name hi.dat`.

Great! But now what if I do **not** want to look at folder D? Can I try something like:

`find * not D/* -name hi.dat`?

I do not want to type:

`find A/* B/* C/* -name ...` because I obviously have more than three folders and those were just used as an example.

Thanks!
Amit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
find !(D) -name hi.dat
```

Ksh and zsh work similarly.

Comment: oh man. so do I type this in the command line?

Comment: @Amit: Yes, where else? The `extglob` option may already be set. You can check by doing `shopt extglob`, if it says "on", you're set. If not, you can add the `shopt -s extglob` to your `~/.bashrc` and it will be set for you when you start Bash. Once it's set by any of those methods, all you need to type is the `find` command.

Comment: @Dennis: This is actually very convenient. So if I type what you wrote, this looks in all current files/directories under where I am currently located?

Comment: Oh this works like a charm. SO much easier to remember.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more using this technique? What if I now didn't want A and D? How would that be written?

Comment: If you want to omit three: `!(David|Ed|Frank)`. However, `-prune` is more versatile.

Comment: @Dennis: Okay thank you! I gave both of you +1, I really wish we could give two checks...

Answer (score 12):

That would be `-prune` — but there's a slight trick to it:

```
$ find . \( -name D -prune \) -o -name hi.dat
```

`-prune` means "don't look any further on this path", so you need another branch for directories other than `D`.  (`-o` means "or".)  To skip other paths as well:

```
$ find . \( \( -name D -o -name Dminor \) -prune \) -o -name hi.dat
```

Comment: Hi geekosaur. I have just down-voted your answer. Please have a look at the [M. Meglio's answer](http://superuser.com/a/582336/112297). Hope this will motivate you to improve your answer. Then I may up-vote your answer... Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 4):

A more general find command is

```
find -path ./D -prune -o -name hi.dat -print
```

*Caveat*: the `-path` test might not yet be portable/part of a POSIX standard.

*Rationale*: In a directory structure like the following

```
$ find
.
./D
./A
./A/D
./A/D/hi.dat
```

compared to

```
$ find . \( -name D -prune \) -o -name hi.dat
./D
./A/D
```

it will only list the files actually searched for (explicit `-print`) and it will not omit files in subdirectories also named D (`-path`):

```
$ find -path ./D -prune -o -name hi.dat -print
./A/D/hi.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

It works piping grep -v,

```
$ find / -name "*~"|grep -v "/media"
```

looks everywhere but not inside media directory

Comment: It will look there but the results will be thrown away so this approach could be pretty inefficient when the paths to be omitted contain a lot of files and directories.

Comment: In fact this is completely wrong approach, because /media can be subdirectory which you do not want to omit, moreover there could be (sub)directory /medial, /median etc, and in this solution you would throw away all those cases.